# I want text in one line but on mobile in 2 lines

Tags: html, css, devise, media-queries, shopify

So I would like to display a specific text 'Designed by...' in one line besides smaller devices like mobile. There I want this specific text to be in a second line.

Here's the current code:

```
<div class="Footer__Copyright">
<a href="{{ shop.url }}" class="Footer__StoreName Heading u-h7 Link Link--secondary">Copyright © {{ shop.name }}</a>  

<div class="text">Designed by <a href="https://www.example.com/">EXAMPLE.</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Image 1. [Mobile (how it should stay)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyGbR.png)
Image 2. [Everything above mobile should be in one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwu1Q.png)

I hope someone can help me with that :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add span instead in div and I used css to style it in the mobiles sizes

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.span{display: inline;}
}
```

```html
<div class="Footer__Copyright">
<a href="{{ shop.url }}" class="Footer__StoreName Heading u-h7 Link Link--secondary">Copyright © {{ shop.name }}</a>  

<span class="text">Designed by <a href="https://www.example.com/">EXAMPLE.</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this works for you :)